# Virtualbox shared clipboard string size limit

Tags: virtualbox

Virtualbox shared clipboard doesn't work if I copy paste a large string from host to guest.

Through some trial and error I determined it seems to break when I go over 512 characters of string length.

Is this a know limitation? Can I increase it somehow? 512 char limit is very low, most configuration files are larger than that.

Comment: I also get this issue--W10 host to Ubuntu 18.04 guest using VirtualBox 6.1.6. Issue is reported here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19314

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update of VirtualBox GuestAdditions should solve your issue.

Comment: Do you have a reference, say on Virtualbox forum? Which version was this fixed in? This bug is filed under ticket 19314 on their issue tracker. The last comment says, it's still not resolved.

Comment: Hi, In my case I was upgrading VBox 6.0.12 -> 6.1.14 and faced the aforementioned issue. Applying the latest GuestAdditions from 6.1.14 solved it.

Comment: Version 6.1.8 works as well